# UILongPressGestureRecognizer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am new to Swift 3 and wanted to create a little To-Do-List. But in viewDidLoad the App always crashes, because of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I searched in the internet, but I found no working solution.

Here's my code and everytime it says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" in the line with UILongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var newButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!

var todoList = Todo.load(){
    didSet{
        Todo.save(todoList)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.2
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
}


func handleLongPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gesture.state != .began { return }
    let pt = gesture.location(in: tableView)
    let path = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pt)
    if let row = (path as NSIndexPath?)?.row,
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path!){
    showPopup(sender: cell, mode: "edit", text: todoList[row], row: row)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the todo.txt file:

```
struct Todo {
static func save(_ data: [String]){
    if let url = docUrl(for: "todo.txt"){
        do {
            let str = data.joined(separator: "\n")
            try str.write(to: url, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
static func load() -> [String] {
    if let url = docUrl(for: "todo.txt"){
        do{
            let str = try String(contentsOf: url,
                                 encoding: .utf8)
            return str.characters
                .split {$0 == "\n"}
                .map { String($0)}
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return []
}
private static func docUrl(for filename: String) -> URL? {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                        in: .userDomainMask)
    if let docDir = urls.first {
        return docDir.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Here is my Error-Report:

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “todo.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/mkartds/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D70E1CB-6D29-49E4-BCD1-316B5022F085/data/Containers/Data/Application/34869E75-E498-4674-B504-E7867935E3FE/Documents/todo.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x61000004a830 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

(lldb)

What should I do?

Comment: Please share error log trace, I'm having this working, maybe issue is somewhere else.

Comment: **Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1** Means you have accidentally activated the breakpoint, simply remove or disable it.

Comment: I added the Error-Report to my Question! But I could solve that right now!

Comment: @Jan This means there is no error on LongPress gesture, the error it self says the file todo.txt does not exist and you are trying to modify it which is not possible.

Comment: I just added the file, but when I delete the UILongPressGestureRecognizer, there is a breakpoint in viewDidLoad though. In a blank line.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using `todo.txt` file in code, probably you're calling it on Directory instead of main bundle.

Comment: I added it to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've added `todo.txt` file in your project's target.

Try updating `docUrl` method with following,

```
private static func docUrl() -> URL? {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "todo", ofType: "txt")
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    return fileURL
}
```

Deactivate your breakpoints:

[image]

Comment: I get the same breakpoint, even when I delete the UILongPressGestureRecognizer part, but without any error! Just :"(lldb)"